# AWS account creation using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create new aws account within our AWS org, but I am still getting no changes after terraform plan:

*"No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed."*

Am I missing something? This is the code:

```
resource "aws_organizations_account" "new_aws_member_account" {
  name  = "XXX"
  email = "XXX@XXX"
  iam_user_access_to_billing = "ALLOW"
}
```

I already tried to deploy new IAM policy (within AWS org account) and there was no problem, but I just can't create new account using this code, I probably missed something, but don't know what.

Our AWS org is created manually using AWS console, so not via terraform, but this shouldn't be a problem or yes?

Can you help please?

Comment: So let me just try to understand: you are trying to create a new member account under a master account?

Comment: @MarkoE yes exactly, under a master account, where we have AWS org enabled, and there are already a lot of member accounts, but I just wanted to try to start create them via terraform, but without success...

Comment: Is there already an account with that email address?

Comment: I haven't really done this with Terraform, but wouldn't you need a `parent_id`?

Comment: @Parsifal no I just double-checked that there is no account with the same email address.

Comment: @MarkoE parent_id? You mean aws account id of the master account, in the code? I didn't find anything similar here - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/organizations_account

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/organizations_account#parent_id

Comment: @MarkoE no luck, even I added parent_id result is still the same.

Comment: One common thing that happens to me is that I forget to change the working directory and I run plan inside of a directory where nothing has changed.

Comment: @MarkoE yeah, it's unbelievable, I tried so hard .... to find the issue, but in the end, it was as you said, the wrong directory. Stupid mistake... Thanks a lot Marko :)

Comment: Haha, happens to the best of us. :D